# Stop Intellij debugger stepping into Spring classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm debugging my Spring Boot app with IntelliJ. I'm pressing step over and the debugger steps into built in Spring classes like "InvocableHandlerMethod". How can I debug only my code and not go into Spring classes.

```
@GetMapping("/restapi")
public String restapi() {
    String result = "hello"; // breakpoint
    return result; // after this statement 
         //debugger goes into InvocableHandlerMethod
}
```

Now, this is not the best example, I tried to find where the debugger went inside Spring's classes in the middle of a method, but I could not.

I searched, did not find answear.

Comment: It could happpen that there's an exception and the debugger is following the exception path.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on in the framework's classes, but I bet is not an exception. Unless Spring throws the exception and leaves the catch empty.

Comment: Share a piece of code showing where this is happening

Comment: I added the code to the post.

Comment: What is `player`? Where is it coming from? This is not a working code snippet

Comment: It is now. Player doesn't matter.

Comment: But of course the debugger will go into Spring classes because there's no more code but going into the framework itself. What are you expecting to happen here?